# "Reply All" , "Reply" and "Forward" buttons not visible in the Send Email Activity on an Apex generated email

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service, emailmessage

I have an Email Service with an Apex class that creates a new EmailMessage object associating the sender with a Contact in the system and the recipient as a User. The email shows up correctly with all the fields populated but without the "Reply" buttons. When I create an email from a User to a User the buttons are visible.

I am also creating an EmailMessageRelation as per the EmailMessage docs, and setting the ToIds field on the EmailMessage which is supposed to automatically associate it with the recipient (User) as described in the following docs snippet:

[image]

According to the above I should have the "Reply" functionality but for some reason I am not getting it. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is that email has also been logged as task?

Comment: Yes, a Task is automatically created by Salesforce.

Comment: Did you check this documentation? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000265937&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: Yes I did. I believe all my settings and code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I got it to work by adding two separate `EmailMessageRelation` objects; one for the sender (in my case a `Contact`) with the `RelationType` set to "FromAddress" and an additional one for the recipient (in my case a `User`) with the `RelationType` set to "ToAddress". Apparently the documentation for `EmailMessage` is not precise since adding the `ToAddress` and `ToIds` fields set to the `User` did not automatically associate the recipient with the `User` and in fact I removed those fields and it works fine.

Here is the relevant working code:

```
EmailMessage newEmail = new EmailMessage();
    newEmail.Status = '2'; //sent
    newEmail.Subject = email.subject;
    newEmail.TextBody = textBody;
    newEmail.HtmlBody = htmlBody;
    newEmail.RelatedToId = recordId;
    newEmail.Incoming = true;

Contact senderContact = ContactRepository.getContactByEmail(jsonObject.get('sender email'));

    if (senderContact != null) {
        Id messageId = AddSenderToMessage(senderContact, newEmail);
        AddEmailRelationship(messageId, senderContact.Id, 'FromAddress');
        AddEmailRelationship(messageId, recipient.Id, 'ToAddress');

        result.success = true;
        return result;
    }

private Id AddSenderToMessage(Contact contact, EmailMessage newEmail) {
    newEmail.FromName = contact.Name;
    newEmail.FromAddress = contact.Email;
    insert newEmail;
    return newEmail.Id;
}
```