# Make Lightning buttons Reply/Reply All/Forward visible for everyone

Tags: lightning, apex-email-service, emailmessage

As per documentation Reply/Reply All/Forward buttons on EmailMessage are visible only for users who are mentioned in To/CC/BCC.

In our case we need whole support department to be able to reply any email that was sent to some common mailbox (for example support@mycompany.com)

It sounds weird that only individual who receive an email can reply it and there is no way somebody else can pick up communication with client.

Is there any configuration (public groups/org-wide email/ etc) or automation (flow/apex) to make reply.. buttons visible for everyone?

UPD: Buttons that I need to be available for everyone are on a screenshot below:
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Read the Notes section (and follow the links) in [this Knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316258&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) . Emails that come from Email-to-Case are not subject to those restrictions.

Comment: It is not about email to case. It is about custom email handler (we create EmailMessage in a handler class)

Comment: Are you using a custom lwc for the UI portion of this?

Comment: You'll need to add those options to the global publisher then it should be available. I ran into this issue a couple weeks back. Go to setup -> publisher layouts and add the email option into any publishers necessary

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - I do not user any custom lightning stuff for that.

Comment: @LogieC This is already done. Still the only person who is in FROM/TO/CC can see those buttons.

Comment: Where are you looking for users to see these buttons? On the activity feed, email message related list, etc?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves on a emailmessage record page. I have updated question description with the screenshot

Comment: Have you checked your emailMessage page layout and confirmed that those buttons are all under the `Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions`? Otherwise, it might be useful to see how you're saving the email in your class similar to the solution [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246715/reply-all-reply-and-forward-buttons-not-visible-in-the-send-email-activi)